# Convert tuples to a dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

for the list of tuples below:

```
[('a',1),('b', 2)]
```

I want to convert it to:

```
[{'a' : 1}, {'b', 2}]
```

which is a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [{k: v} for k, v in lst]
```

Where `lst` is your list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
[{t[0] : t[1]} for t in [('a',1),('b', 2)]]
```